# Hard refresh IE11 frame source

Tags: css, caching, internet-explorer-11

I have updated my css for iframe in and it works fine in chrome browser with proper version number like mycss-1.0.1.css. However, in IE11 it still showing me mycss-1.0.0.css which was the initial version or my css.

I have hard refresh by pressing Ctrl+F5. I have also cleared the cache of my IE11 as well but still no luck.

I have also tried to refresh my `iframe` from console of IE11. `document.getElementById('DynamicGui__502').contentWindow.location.reload();`

Comment: I have also tried to refresh my iframe from console of ie11.

document.getElementById('DynamicGui__502').contentWindow.location.reload();

Comment: Try change the link -  mycss-1.0.1.css?v=1.0.1 on your html to avoid cache problems

Comment: If you use the dev tools in IE can you see which CSS file the iframe is loading and verify that it tries to load `mycss-1.0.1.css`?

Comment: Got it resolved. it was my DB issue. Thanks Anyway

Comment: Could you post your solution so that others who have a similar problem know where to look...

Comment: my link text coming form database and my db was not updated so that was the reason.